# How record values entered in a form to a List or collection in ASP MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I am developing an ASP .Net MVC 3 application using C# and SQL Server 2005.

I am using also Entity Framework and Code First Method.

I have this form :
[image]

I want to save the values entred in a list (or collection) when I click in the button 'Enregistrer'.

This is the code of the View :

```
 <fieldset class="parametrage">
        <legend>Gestion de Gamme</legend>

        <div><%:Html.Label("Poste :")%><%: Html.DropDownList("SelectedPoste", Model.PostesItems)%><input type="checkbox" name="option1" value="Poste Initial" id= "chkMain" onclick="test();"/>Poste Initial<input type="checkbox" name="option2" value="Poste Final" id= "chkFirst" onclick="test2();"/>Poste Final</div>


         <div><%:Html.Label("Nombre de Passage :")%><%: Html.EditorFor(x=>x.YourGammeModel.Nbr_Passage)%></div>
        <div><%:Html.Label("Position :")%><%: Html.EditorFor(x=>x.YourGammeModel.Position)%></div>
        <div><%:Html.Label("Poste Précédent :")%><%: Html.DropDownList("PostePrecedentSelected", Model.PostesItems)%></div>
        <div><%:Html.Label("Poste Suivant :")%><%: Html.DropDownList("PosteSuivantSelected", Model.PostesItems)%></div>


        <div><input type="submit" value="Enregistrer" id="btnSave"  /></div>

        </fieldset>
```

The ViewModel :

```
private static Dictionary<string, Gamme> userGammes; 

public static Dictionary<string, Gamme> UserGammes 
{ 
    get 
    { 
        if (userGammes == null) 
        { 
            userGammes = new Dictionary<string, Gamme>(); 
        } 
        return userGammes; 
    } 
}
```

and the controller :

```
    public ActionResult Save(Gamme gamme)
    {
        UserGammes.Add("currentUserID", gamme);
    }
```

Comment: Alright. What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: @OndrejTucny yes I tried,,,please check my update,,but the statement in the controller is not accepted by VS

Comment: I would suggest completing tutorials here before going into your own project. http://www.asp.net/mvc

Comment: @emrenevayeshirazi i have read all the tutos !!!! I am tried many things but I am stuck ,,,sorry I forget to put my solution at first,,,but when you check the update again,,you will see what i tried to do

Comment: You posted many questions related to the same small program, asking for help with its step-by-step completion. This is not the way forward: when you don't understand both the big picture and the details, you should first learn the topic from consistent sources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, you would use a collection when you have a list of similar things that can be selected (i.e., a multi-select list box).  The *M* in *MVC* is the data *model*.  It doesn't really work without that.

You should create a class that contains the fields you need and then pass that class to your view, e.g.:

```
public class UserGammeModel {
  public string PosteItems
  public string NobreDePassage { get; set; }
  public string Position { get; set; }
  public Gamme PostePrecedent { get; set; }
  public Gamme PosteSuivant { get; set; }
}
```

Use whatever object types make sense for your model class properties--the more strongly-typed, the better!

Then pass your model to the view in a controller GET action method:

```
public ActionResult Save() {
  return View(new UserGammeModel());
}
```

Finally, handle the posted values in a controller POST action method:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Save(UserGammeModel model) {
  // Do stuff with posted model values here
}
```

Comment: thx peter,,but where i will pass my model to the view ?

Comment: In a controller GET action method, as he stated above...

Comment: @Evanlewis the problem, I have already a model 'Gamme' ! so I will not create a new class like Peter said,,,,but I have to put the methods in the Controller named AnouarController because it is the one which populate the view of my form

Comment: I sustain that Peter's solution is the most MVC consistant... I'm no expert on the matter, but it doesn't seem like you are willing to try a more consistant method.  I will slink away now...